# QtPy Running a process looping through features

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, pyqt, iteration

I'm writing an iterator to run a processing on an individual feature of a layer.

In this example: gray region included green bordered cells and black points. I want to run a processing 'count points in polygon' (just for the case of this example) for each feature, save it to a new layer lyrProc and then copy from lyrProc to a new layer 'newDepot'.

I can't figure out saving the results of the processing and adding them to a new layer. I get a layer with correct number of elements but empty table of contents.
How do I solve this? Where too look for a solution?

[image]

```
import time
from qgis import processing

mc = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
output = rf"C:\output\\"

depot_layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('gray_region')
rej_layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('green_border_cells')
point_layers =  QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points')

lyrDepot = depot_layers[0]
lyrRej = rej_layers[0]
lyrPoints =  point_layers[0]

tmStart = time.time()

if len(depot_layers)>0:
    if lyrDepot.isValid:
    
    newDept = iface.addVectorLayer("polygon","newDept","memory")
    newDept.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4258))
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newDept)
    
    processing.run("native:selectbylocation", 
    {'INPUT':lyrRej.sourceName(),
    'PREDICATE':[6],
    'INTERSECT':lyrDepot.sourceName(),
    'METHOD':0})

    counter = 0 
    for ftr in lyrRej.selectedFeatures():
        #procLyr = QgsVectorLayer("polygon","proc_lyr","memory")
        procLyr = iface.addVectorLayer("polygon","proc_lyr","memory")
        procLyr.startEditing()
        procLyr.dataProvider().addFeature(ftr)
        procLyr.commitChanges()
    
        newDept.startEditing()
        
        processing.run("native:countpointsinpolygon", {\
        'POLYGONS':procLyr.sourceName(),\
        'POINTS':lyrPoints.sourceName(),\
        'WEIGHT':'',\
        'CLASSFIELD':'',\
        'FIELD':'NUMPOINTS',\
        'OUTPUT':'proc_lyr')

        newDept.dataProvider().addFeature(procLyr.getFeature(0))
        QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(procLyr)

        newDept.commitChanges()
        counter+=1
        
    lyrRej.removeSelection()
    print("Done")

else:
    print("invalid")

tmEnd = time.time()
print("Run time = {0:.3f} seconds".format(tmEnd-tmStart))
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what result you want to get. You have two polygon layers and one point layer, what do you want to do with them?

Answer (score 1):

Posting the code that gave me desired output.

One layer with count of points inside of polygons.

[image]

```py
    import time
    from qgis import processing

    mc = iface.mapCanvas()

    # create project layer list
    layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
    output = rf"C:\Users\amkor\Desktop\robota\olx projekty\AAA 
    Patryk\dane\output\\"

    depot_layers = 
    QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('A01_Granice_wojewodztw')
    rej_layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('gminy_małe')
    point_layers =  
    QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('PRG_PunktyAdresowe_10')

    lyrDept = depot_layers[0]
    lyrRej = rej_layers[0]
    lyrPts =  point_layers[0]

    tmStart = time.time()


if len(depot_layers)>0:
    if lyrDept.isValid:
        
        fieldsRej = lyrRej.fields()
        counter = 0 
        
        # create new layer - final product
        newDept = iface.addVectorLayer("polygon","newDept","memory")
        newDept.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326))
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newDept)
        
        processing.run("native:selectbylocation", 
        {'INPUT':lyrRej.sourceName(),
        'PREDICATE':[6],
        'INTERSECT':lyrDept.sourceName(),
        'METHOD':0})

        for ftr in lyrRej.selectedFeatures():
            # create processing layer out of single feature (required for processing input)
            procLyr = iface.addVectorLayer("polygon","proc_lyr","memory")
            procLyr.startEditing()
            # add fields to this layer
            for fieldRej in fieldsRej:
                procLyr.addAttribute(fieldRej)
            procLyr.commitChanges()
            # add the feature to the layer
            procLyr.dataProvider().addFeature(ftr)
            procLyr.commitChanges()
            
            resultLyr = processing.run("native:countpointsinpolygon", {\
            'POLYGONS':procLyr.sourceName(),\
            'POINTS':lyrPts.sourceName(),\
            'FIELD':'NUMPOINTS',\
            'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
            
            #add attributes to newDept layer
            if counter == 0:
                newDept.startEditing()
                fieldsOut = resultLyr['OUTPUT'].fields()
                for fieldOut in fieldsOut:
                    newDept.addAttribute(fieldOut)
                newDept.commitChanges()

            # add new feature to newDept
            for nFtr in resultLyr['OUTPUT'].getFeatures():
                newDept.dataProvider().addFeature(nFtr)
            
            QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(procLyr)
            counter+=1
        
        lyrRej.removeSelection()

    else:
        print("Layer invalid")

tmEnd = time.time()
print("Run time = {0:.3f} seconds".format(tmEnd-tmStart))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you need to add fields to the new "procLyr" layer so that it is not empty. Below I'm adding fields from the "lyrRej" layer.

```
procLyr = iface.addVectorLayer("polygon","proc_lyr","memory")
procLyr.startEditing()
fields = lyrRej.fields()
for field in fields:
    procLyr.addAttribute(field)
procLyr.commitChanges()
```

After adding fields to the "procLyr" layer, you can add the feature from "lyrRej" to it.

2. Get out the output layer from the algorithm "CountPointsinpolygon" can be as follows:

```
alg_params = {
    'POLYGONS':procLyr,
    'POINTS':lyrPoints,
    'WEIGHT':'',
    'CLASSFIELD':'',
    'FIELD':'NUMPOINTS',
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
}
final_proc_lyr = processing.run("native:countpointsinpolygon", alg_params)['OUTPUT']
# add layer to mapcanvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(final_proc_lyr)
```

Comment: thank you! That was very helpful about the attribute table.

Comment: In the end I want to have everything in one layer. I want to process each feature from lyrRej separately and add it to newly created layer newDept. 
 

And still, my biggest problem is how to save features one by one to newDept? 

My idea was to save each feature to a memory layer (which now I see here is wrong, it shouldn't be proc_lyr, but it doesn't change much) and later from there to newDept. Is this a good idea? 


Where are memory layers processing outputs stored? How do I access them?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope it helps. In this way, you can get the output layer of an algorithm, add it to a map, or use it as an input layer for another algorithm.

Comment: Thank u so much again, I finally figured it out. For some reason accessing feature through .getFeatures() instead of .getFeature(0) solved the problem. I'll clean up the code and upload it shortly.